# Can you change the prefs in Eclipse to make your commenting italicized?

Tags: eclipse, comments

I was wondering if there is the ability to make your comments in code italic like you can in VisualStudio. It would be a lot easier to read the comments if they stood out.

I've googled this plenty of times and found nothing and figured if anybody knows someone here would know lol.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring.

There should be a Comments node in the Elements table in the top left.

You can select single/multi line comments and click the Italic checkbox.